# Launch Front Camera On a Button Click

Tags: android, camera

i just want to know is there any way to launch the front camera using just intent. i don't want to use intent.putextra thing. so basically my code should look like this

```
   btnFrontCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent camera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivity(camera);
        }
    });
```

But above code is launching the back camera. i want to launch the front camera directly. 
Help me with this if it is possible in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i just want to know is there any way to launch the front camera using just intent

No.

> i don't want to use intent.putextra thing.

That is fine, as there is no "intent.putextra thing" that controls which hardware camera the user's chosen camera app will use. The choice of camera is between the camera app and the user, through the camera app's UI. You do not get a vote.

If you want to take a picture and force that to be taken using a front-facing camera (if one is available), you will need to take the picture yourself using the camera APIs, not by invoking a third-party camera app.

Comment: @CommonWare : Ok, Thank you for your Quick reply